# I want to see errors in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am tired of these not saying much error messages in official drupal 7 extensions `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later`

How do I show debug info, or the regular error message?

I checked bootstrap.inc and played around with the error settings, but it keeps on not showing me any more info.

Can someone give me the golden tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the built in log reports:
admin menu: Reports/Recent log messages
/admin/reports/dblog

or check apache log.